# How to procedurally generate materials with text in Unity

Tags: unity, procedural-generation, text, materials, substance-engine

I'm designing a virtual library that dynamically loads sections of a database and need to display text on the books. As such, I need a runtime interface to somehow load book titles and author and put them on the book covers.

I've looked into Substance Designer to make a procedural material, but the Text Node in the program is not yet supported by Unity. I've also stumbled across `TextGenerator` in the Unity API, but it seems to be mesh not texture based, and I'm not sure what the performance penalty will be, given I'm rendering a lot of books.

**Edit:** For now I had some luck creating a child object and using the `TextGenerator`, since it turns out the mesh is minimal and in fact does create a texture to display the text. I suppose I can use this solution until something better comes up.

Comment: I figured out how to render text to the screen manually (raw OpenGL) once about...year and a half ago?  Took a few days, but it wasn't that hard. I think the same process could render to a texture too, but I haven't done that much texture-modification work.

Comment: To clarify: are you displaying predetermined text (i.e. strings loaded from your database) or are you dynamically composing the text at runtime?

Comment: Predetermined text from the database, I updated the question with a new workaround I found

Comment: If that solved your question, you should [post it as an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) & accept it. If it doesn't solve your problem, please elaborate as to how your temporary solution fails to adequately solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I had some luck creating a child object and using the TextGenerator, since it turns out the mesh is minimal and in fact does create a texture to display the text. I suppose I can use this solution until something better comes up.